# If a non 'word' character is specified in a RegEx string with \b, will the 'word' still match?'

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript will regex properly match \bmyword_txt_\b to myword_txt_ as a 'word?'

Comment: Have you tried it? You should probably do that if you haven't.

Comment: Code sample and source text? what is the regex you're actually using? Could you at least provide a fiddle?

Comment: Please review this and provide an example:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is a word for you? If a string consisting of letters, digits and underscore, `\b` will work. Else, build your custom word boundary.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies. I want the regex match to be able to differentiate between myword and myword_ for example.

Answer (score 0):

YES it will work try:

```
"XXX myword_txt_ 123 NNN".match(/\bmyword_txt_\b/)
```

It will match the myword_txt_ as expected.

If you need to find several instances of the myword_txt_ use global modifier in regex definition: /\bmyword_txt_\b/**g**